# Removing shadow from ScatterViewItem isn't working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

I always used this code to remove the shadow from a ScatterViewItem:

```
 ScatterViewItem svi = new ScatterViewItem();
 svi.ApplyTemplate();
 svi.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
 svi.ShowsActivationEffects = false;
 svi.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
 Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.SurfaceShadowChrome ssc;
 ssc = svi.Template.FindName("shadow", svi) as Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.SurfaceShadowChrome;
 ssc.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

But recently this isn't working anymore. I always get this exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Prototype_Concept_2
  StackTrace:
       at Prototype_Concept_2.PackageView.expand(Package pck) in C:\Users\Roflcoptr\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Prototype_Concept_2\Prototype_Concept_2\PackageView.xaml.cs:line 45
       at Prototype_Concept_2.PackageView..ctor(SourceFile focus) in C:\Users\Roflcoptr\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Prototype_Concept_2\Prototype_Concept_2\PackageView.xaml.cs:line 31
       at Prototype_Concept_2.DetailChooser.ShowPackage_PreviewContactDown(Object sender, ContactEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Roflcoptr\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Prototype_Concept_2\Prototype_Concept_2\DetailChooser.xaml.cs:line 213
       at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.ContactEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
       at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
       at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.InputSurfaceProviderBase.DoProcessInput(Object obj)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at Prototype_Concept_2.App.Main() in C:\Users\Roflcoptr\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Prototype_Concept_2\Prototype_Concept_2\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

This means that in the line  `ssc = svi.Template.FindName("shadow", svi) as Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.SurfaceShadowChrome;`
there must be a NullReference, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `ApplyTemplate` returns false, so the Template isn't applied, meaning it's null. This explains the `NullReferenceException`. What you can do is to attach an eventhandler which subsribes to the Loaded event of the `ScatterViewItem` and in the handler you do the same thing. In WPF, the template has always been applied when the Loaded event occurs

```
ScatterViewItem svi = new ScatterViewItem();
svi.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
svi.ShowsActivationEffects = false;
svi.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;

RoutedEventHandler loadedEventHandler = null;
loadedEventHandler = new RoutedEventHandler(delegate
{
    svi.Loaded -= loadedEventHandler;
    Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.SurfaceShadowChrome ssc;
    ssc = svi.Template.FindName("shadow", svi) as Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.SurfaceShadowChrome;
    ssc.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
});
svi.Loaded += loadedEventHandler;
```

Comment: I'll award the bounty as soons as the time limit is exceeded.

Comment: It couldn't find ```Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.SurfaceShadowChrome``` class. But I used CustomShadowChrome from Sample projects' ScatterPuzzle. And copied your code inside of the method body. It is hiding whole item. Am I doing something wrong?